# can I create Collections in Flickr using Flickr API

Tags: flickr

Can I create Collections using Flickr API (I am using C# FlickerNet, but I can use REST calls, if its supported). I am not getting any method for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flickr.photosets.create](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.create.html) to make a new photoset.  Photosets are similar to collections, and perhaps their differences won't be important to your requirements.

Comment: Hi,
I am aware of photoset and know how to create them through API. My requirement is precisely creating COLLECTIONS.
Thanks.